# Concatenate merged cells with non sequential columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table where I am trying to concatenate merged cell with other column values

[image]
I used this formula to get the concatenation done,

```
=ArrayFormula(query(byrow(
{lookup(row(A3:A),row(A3:A)/(A3:A<>""),A3:A),D3:G},
lambda(r,textjoin("-",1,r))),
"limit "&-1+max(F3:G11<>"",row(F3:G11))))
```

but I want to exclude column by name `BF` from the concatenation.

I only want `Name`, `Frequency`, `Old Measure` and `New Measure` columns to be concatenated

Please help in guiding me here. @ztiaa @Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to split up your array ranges in your `byRow` array with a comma.  Try this...

```
=ArrayFormula(query(byrow(
{lookup(row(A3:A),row(A3:A)/(A3:A<>""),A3:A),D3:D,F3:G},
lambda(r,textjoin("-",1,r))),
"select Col1 limit "&-1+max(F3:G11<>"",row(F3:G11))))
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(LAMBDA(c, LAMBDA(a, b, BYROW({VLOOKUP(ROW(a), IF(a<>"", {ROW(a), a}), 2), 
 IF(b="",,"-"&b)}, LAMBDA(x, JOIN(, x))))
 (A2:INDEX(A:A, c), D2:INDEX(G:G, c)))(MAX(ROW(A:A)*(A:G<>""))))
```

[image]

[image]